# How to create a focus blur effect in css?

Tags: css, blur

I am trying to create a focus effect with blur but i faced a huge problem. :)

I need something like this:

[Focus effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPmwu.png)

But all examples in internet are about blocks with fixed position. Clip-path and radial-gradient doesn't work if position of element is absolute. My block has 700px height and I can scroll it.

The only effect I reached:

[No blur effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAq20.png)

But I want to see blurred literas.

Is it possible?

Here what I tried (short version):

```
<div class="black-promo">
  <div class="black-promo__blur"></div>
</div>

.black-promo {
  background: black;
  position: relative;
  height: 700px;


  &__blur {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
    background: radial-gradient(circle, #0000 150px, rgba(45, 45, 45, 0.9) 300px);
  }
}
```

Try number 2:

https://codepen.io/Nnekkka/pen/xxagZQQ

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally what you want to do is to cut out a hole in your overlay element, and apply the `backdrop-filter` property on the overlay, to blur what's under it. Here's an example cutting out a hole with with the [`mask`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask) property. Note it needs a vendor prefix (`-webkit-`) for Chrome.

https://codepen.io/andrewray/pen/JjaEGOa

```
.div-with-hole {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  height: 100vh;
  -webkit-mask: radial-gradient(50px, #0000 98%, #000);
          mask: radial-gradient(50px, #0000 98%, #000);
  width: 100%;
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
  background:rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

[image: hole cut out blur filter]

Comment: I got blurred hole. It doesnt work in my case because my block is inside parent block with position relative.

Comment: Thank you!! I found the reason why your example didn't work in my case! I removed overflow hidden and it works!

Comment: Awesome, if this answered your question, can you click the empty check mark next to it to mark it as correct, to help others find it, and to give me fake internet points?

Comment: @AndyRay Can this work on a live web-cam stream? I would like an oval area right at the center to be clear while everything outside it to be a bit blur as to indicate the user to place the head inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Using this CSS:
backdrop-filter: blur(3px);

Comment: Everything will be blurred, but I need not bluerred center.